# Is there a means to configure per-module log levels in lager for erlang?

Tags: erlang, lager

I would like to configure lager so that the default level of info is used for all other modules but I can override certain modules either higher or lower log levels as desired. The following code does not work though I found it in an issue report on lager.

```
{lager_console_backend, [
  {level, info},
  {formatter, lager_default_formatter},
  {formatter_config, [color, time, " [", sev, "] [", module, ", ", pid, "] ", message, "\e[0m\r\n"]},
  {level_overrides, [ % TODO This doesn't work.
    {myriad_cloud_sup, debug}
  ]}
]}
```

Anyone have any idea how this could be done?